# Send and process FormData

Tags: javascript, ajax, form-data

I've been struggling for hours with following code without success. In my html I have several inputs (type=text, type=date and selects), and a button calling a js function: `onclick=SendNewData()`.

The JS function is something like the following:

```
function SendNewData() {
     var MyData1=document.getElementById("id1").value;
     var MyData2=document.getElementById("id2").value;
     var MyData3=document.getElementById("id3").value;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }   
    xhr.open('POST', 'Handler.php', true);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("FormNuevaCom").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;   
        }
    }

    var data = new FormData;
    data.append('DATA1', MyData1);
    data.append('DATA2', MyData2);
    data.append('DATA3', MyData3);

    xhr.send(data);     
}
```

and the `Handler.php` is something like the following:

```
if(isset($_POST['DATA1'])) {
    $MyVar=$_POST['DATA1'];
    echo "Hi there! ".$MyVar." received...";

}
```

I can´t get any response. Anyone can spot the problem?

Comment: Does your request header contains the above data?

Comment: Don't know what you mean by `request header` really. So I think the answer is no, since there's no other code.

Comment: ActiveXObject? Coding for IE6? :/ Open up Chrome DevTools Network tab and look at the request, is it being sent as you expect? Is the PHP server receiving the request?

Comment: open up the network tab in your devtools and submit form data.Go to XHR tab,click on the endpoint ->in the description u will find the header request

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump($_POST);` in your php file ?! what is the output ?

Comment: Trying to learn usage of devtools as quickly as possible. I can see (in FF inspector) that data is sent, and the response is the expected one. However its not displaying properly on the page. Will keep on inspecting for the error. Thank you all for the input.